# Check is variable is array or not with XCTest

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, xcode, xctest

Do how to know if variable return function is an array or not ? Example:
In my Presenter I have this function:

```
 func filterGnomosForName(name:String) -> [Gnomo]{
    let res = listGnomos.filter { ($0.name?.lowercased().contains(name.lowercased()))!}
    return res
}
```

And MyTestClass I have this test function:

```
    func testFilterGnomo(){
    let result = listPresenter.filterGnomosForName(name: "Nam")
    XCTAssert(result == [Gnomo])
}
```

Gnomo is a type object in array , but only want know if is array or not for know if the funcion is correctly or not , help me?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When I am asserting an objects type I do this:

```
XCTAssert((object as Any) is Array)
```

I've not asserted an array before but I think the above would work.

Here is an example I just created in a Swift Playground:

```
import UIKit
import XCTest

class MyTestClass: XCTestCase {

    func testSomething() {
        let myArray: [String] = ["foo", "bar"]

        XCTAssert((myArray as Any) is String) // Fails
        XCTAssert((myArray as Any) is [String]) // Passes
    }
}

MyTestClass.defaultTestSuite().run()
```

Comment: Not if you cast it to `Any` first. I've added some more example code to my answer to show a working example.